# Routing subdomains in Pyramid

Tags: python, url, url-routing, pylons, pyramid

In Pylons 1.0 I could go into config/routing.py and add

```
map.connect('/', controller='index', conditions=dict(sub_domain=False))
map.connect('/', controller='mobileindex', conditions=dict(sub_domain='m'))
```

to route m.mydomain.com to a different controller, but still use the same app. Can I do the same in Pyramid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, this is covered by [`add_route()`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_route) with a [pregenerator](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/interfaces.html#pyramid.interfaces.IRoutePregenerator) argument.

Answer (score 1):

An example of what @syrion is referring to is available here:

[Multiple domains and subdomains on a single Pyramid instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607807/multiple-domains-and-subdomains-on-a-single-pyramid-instance)