# Multiple domains and subdomains on a single Pyramid instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm looking to have multiple domains and subdomains on a single Pyramid instance. However, I can't seem to find any documentation on it. The last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274813/routing-subdomains-in-pyramid) referred to a glossary with very little information and no examples. Do any of you have any examples or can direct me to better documentation?

Comment: This is a fairly old question, but I've use Paste#urlmap to do this with Pyramid: http://pythonpaste.org/modules/urlmap.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pyramid is just a WSGI application. This means it's dependent on the HTTP_HOST environ key (set by the Host header) to determine the host of the application. It's all relative. Point-being that Pyramid has no restrictions on what it can accept, thus the world is your oyster and you can set it up to limit content to various domains however you'd like. This of course starts with what hosts your webserver is configured to feed to your application.

Assuming you're using URL dispatch, you might want to design some custom route predicates that check the `request.host` value for whatever you'd like. Returning `False` from that predicate will prevent that route from ever matching a request to that host.

This is a large topic, so it might help if you give some more specifics. For example, since Pyramid is relative, any URL you may want to generate from 'example.com' to redirect someone to 'sub.example.com' will need to be done via a pregenerator.

```
def pregen(request, elements, kw):
    kw['_app_url'] = 'http://sub.example.com'
    return elements, kw

def req_sub(info, request):
    return request.host.startswith('sub')

config.add_route('sub_only', '/',
                 custom_predicates=(req_sub,),
                 pregenerator=pregen)
config.add_route('foo', '/foo')
config.add_view(view, route_name-'foo')

def view(request):
    # redirect the user to "http://sub.example.com", regardless of whether
    # request.host is "example.com" or "sub.example.com"
    return HTTPFound(request.route_url('sub_only'))
```

Comment: My biggest obstacle with learning how this works is that I can't find any examples like this. Do you know where I can find more examples? Thank you!

Comment: For this particular setup I'm not aware of too many examples. Typically different subdomains would represent different WSGI apps and they'd each have their own settings, with probably some shared. There's the Pyramid Cookbook of various examples, but I'm not aware of any regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over your hosting environment, I would *strongly* suggest keeping the domain stuff out of pyramid and handling it with a proxy server such as apache mod proxy, routing to subdomains in pyramid. Then you can easily switch any of the domain name to view routing without having anything fragile (like domain names) in your pyramid code. Your app code will be much cleaner this way, and far easier to change later.

Here's an Apache example of two domains going to one pyramid app, assuming we are serving the pyramid app somehow or another on port 5001 (gunicorn or whatever you want).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain_2.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # send all request to our app at /app1/*
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/app_1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5001/app_1/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain_2.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # send all request to our app at /app2/*
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/app_2/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5001/app_2/

</VirtualHost>
```

And here's an example of one domain going to several pyramid instances:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # admin go to manager app on 5001
    ProxyPass /media/manager/ http://127.0.0.1:5001/ retry=5
    ProxyPassReverse /media/manager/ http://127.0.0.1:5001/

    # downloads from server app on 5002
    ProxyPass /media/server/ http://127.0.0.1:5002/ retry=5
    ProxyPassReverse /media/server/ http://127.0.0.1:5002/

</VirtualHost>
```