# How to create a large website with several subdomains and sharing same models in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm building a e-commerce website which consists of several domains:

```
www.example.com: main website which show all items
passport.example.com: this website handle everything related to users like ordering, user information management and so on
static.example.com: holding static contents
admin.example.com: for admin use
```

The customer ask me to build three websites(website 'static' does not required a application to handle) and put 'em into three servers. These websites need to share models and templates. Should I build three projects? Is there any better way to handle this situation in Pyramid?
Thanks.

Comment: Do these applications run in parallel and modify the same model? In this case I would be careful as you could run into collision. You might want to consult SQLAlchemy's documentation on threads and race conditions. If these applications use the same models but no collision can appear, then you can probably safely import the models into each application seperately. If the interaction is high, I would probably build one application (or solve all collisions/conflicts)

Comment: I don't want to build three separate applications... That's hard to deply and manage. So I wanna know how to solve this problem in a single application...

Comment: Well in this case you should look into subdomains and routing for pyramid. You can find some information here on stackoverflow but it seems it is not that well documented (though possible, I think)

Comment: Could u tell me something more about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is I create a separate python package for my models (and you might want to make another one for your templates), and I `python setup.py develop` it in each project's `virtualenv`. Also, I usually keep all the projects under the same source control repository, to make sure there is no version problem when deploying. You could probably get the same result by using version numbers in your dependencies of the `setup.py` of your different projects.

If this sound new to you, you might want to read http://guide.python-distribute.org/.

Each package has it's `setup.py` telling the package name and version number, and also a list of dependencies.

Comment: That's what I am doing now... But is there any more elegant way to do this? If I need to deploy these three projects in a single server with different subdomains, how can I do?

Comment: If you want to make a single app regrouping all the other apps, you might want to use config.include() to include the other apps in the main app. Also, to route according to subdomains, there might be a better way, but you can always make your own custom predicate, as highlighted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607807/multiple-domains-and-subdomains-on-a-single-pyramid-instance . I don't know your exact needs but I'm not a big fan of trying to make a big app that does it all. I usually prefer to keep things separated in their own packages and served individually.

Comment: yup.. I have already followed your advice and make three applications... but how about the deployment? I have to deploy all of 'em on a single server...

Comment: If you put each of those behind a reverse proxy like nginx, it takes care of sending the requests to the good application according to the subdomain. As for deployment itself, I usually make a deployment script that I run when I want to deploy.

Comment: How about deploy all application in a single server? We only one server at this time. Could you tell me something detailed? Thanks.

Comment: A good starting point would be to deploy each app individually like here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/nginx.html Then you can start to improve your deployments, like automating stuff, package dependencies, etc.