# How do I manipulate subdomains with Pyramid's url dispatch?

Tags: python, pyramid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple domains and subdomains on a single Pyramid instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607807/multiple-domains-and-subdomains-on-a-single-pyramid-instance)

I can not seem to find any documentation on working with subdomains with the Pyramid framework. There is one [question/answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274813/routing-subdomains-in-pyramid) regarding this where they say

> "Theoretically, this is covered by add_route() with a pregenerator
>   argument."

I have also found in the [docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/interfaces.html) where they mention subdomains under the interface IRoutePregenerator

> `__call__(request, elements, kw)`:  " The pregenerator for a route is called by `pyramid.request.Request.route_url()` in order to adjust the
>   set of arguments passed to it by the user for special purposes, such
>   as Pylons ‘subdomain’ support."

But these are the only places that even mention subdomains and there is nothing on how to work with them.

All I am wanting is to have a wildcard DNS accept any subdomain. If subdomain is user, route to a certain controller, if the subdomain is any other word, route to a controller and provide the subdomain as a variable.

This is super easy with Flask:

```
mod = Blueprint('users', __name__, subdomain='user')
@mod.route('/')
code
```

or

```
mod = Blueprint('everything', __name__)
@mod.route('/', subdomain='<var1>')
```

How can I/is it possible to achieve this with Pyramid?